# Add-in to filter Outlook calendar events

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins

Is there any way to add a task pane add-in for Outlook and use it to filter the Calendar events. For example: If I click on a button in the task pane it will only show the appointments for the next day, or filter based on location ...

Any link or tutorial will be very helpful.
Thank you.